# What happens in git merge if one file does not exist in merged branch

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have a question about several merges from different branches.

#### Steps

Consider `A` and `B` are up to date with `Master`.

1. `A` adds some files and changes some other files.
2. `B` also adds some other files.
3. `A` pushes its commits and `Master` merges with `A`.

#### Questions

Now what happens if `B` pushes his commits to merge with `Master`? I thought of some possibilities:

1. Are those files from `A` removed?
2. What about old files that `A` has changed but in `B` they are not changed?

What happens to those?

I am afraid to do it because I think it will remove other's files.

Comment: Do it on a new test repository! But you should generally expect merge to merge changes together and not replace one with the other without asking (in the form of a merge conflict).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Answer (score 1):

When Git does a regular (non-octopus) merge, it considers exactly three points: the two heads that are being merged (A and B), and a point called the *merge base*, which is usually the most recent common ancestor.  The result of the merge is effectively the sum of the differences between the merge base and A and the differences between the merge base and B, assuming there are no conflicts.

Thus, if A added some files that were not in the merge base and B didn't, the result will be that the files exist in the result.  Similarly, if A made some changes to existing files and B didn't modify them, then the result will include those changes.  That's because in both cases, one side has changed and the other has not, so Git adopts the change (trivially, in fact).

The problem comes if both A and B add a file or if they both make changes to the same file in the same area.  In such a case, a conflict will occur, and someone will have to fix it when they merge.

Note that intermediate changes are not considered, only the differences between the merge base and the heads.  If A makes a change and reverts it, and B makes the same change, the result will be that the change is adopted, since A's side had no changes between the merge base and A, and B's side did, so Git will adopt the change.

Comment: In summary, to answer the original question: In the case sketched in the question, all changes from both branches and all files added will be present in the merge result.